# What is the proper way to add a type to a callback function?

Tags: typescript, typescript-eslint

Eslint is giving me an error message with this function. How can I fix it?

Function:

```
export const get = (
  route: string,
  callback: (response: object) => void,
  errorCallback: (response: object) => void,
) => {
  fetch(`${host}/${route}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(callback)
    .catch(error =>
      errorCallback ? errorCallback(error) : console.error(error), <--- error in errorCallback(error) is highlighted
    )
}
```

Error message:

```
Unsafe argument of type `any` assigned to a parameter of type `object`.
```

Use case:

```
get(
  "/route",
  (response) => console.log(response)),
  (error) => console.error(error)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that in JavaScript you can throw and reject anything, not just an (Error) object.

```
throw 'some string';
// Uncaught some string
```

So the argument of the `catch` statement always has type `any`.

---

In your case, you're using `fetch()`, so you know that the error that is caught is an `Error` object (`DOMException` or `TypeError`). But Typescript doesn't know this. You can let Typescript know this by using the `as` keyword.

Additionally, since you check if `errorCallback` is defined, I assume you want to make it optional.

```
export const get = (
  route: string,
  callback: (response: object) => void,
  errorCallback?: (response: object) => void,
) => {
  fetch(`${host}/${route}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(callback)
    .catch(error =>
      errorCallback ? errorCallback(error as Error) : console.error(error),
    )
}
```

Comment: Adding `as Error` did the trick. Can you provide a link that explains this in more detail so I can read more about it? I'm not quite sure what I should be looking up since I'm still learning typescript.

Comment: I'm not sure this is what you want, but check [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) out, and the official term used to describe this, if i'm correct, is type assertion.

Comment: Officially it's called "type assertions", but often people just call it type casting. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions

Answer (score 0):

You specified the type of `errorCallback` argument as object, but you use it as an `Error` object, try defining the function like this -

```js
export const get = (
  route: string,
  callback: (response: object) => void,
  errorCallback: (error: Error) => void,
)
```

Comment: This did not make the eslint error go away. Instead of the message saying `.. of type object` it says `.. of type Error`.

Comment: hmm it doesn't show in my linter. perhaps the error is because you don't specify the type of the `error` argument of the arrow function inside `catch`? try doing `.catch(error: object =>
      errorCallback ? errorCallback(error) : console.error(error), <--- error in errorCallback(error) is highlighted
    )`

Comment: Adding `object` to `error` now gives me `Argument of type 'object' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Error'. Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Error': name, message ts(2345)`. I'll do more research now that I have a new error message.

Comment: The bottom line is that you have defined the `errorCallback` as `(response: object) => void` so it's usage have to match this. if you defined the argument as an object, than you need to explicitly define it as an object when you use it in the catch statement. In the question it doesn't have a type (so `any`) and after the (wrong) fix I suggested it's `Error`. You will choose which type you want to use.